# sqs message between a client and a server

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-sqs

I need to setup a client which will send sqs to a server:

client side:

...
sqs = AWS::SQS.new 
q = sqs.queues.create("q_name") 
m = q.send_message("meta")
...

but how the server could read the message of the client?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to have your server connect to SQS then you can get your queue.
Do a get_messages on your queue.  Go to [boto docs](http://boto.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ref/sqs.html) to get more information on the attributes.  This will give you 1 to 10 message objects based on your parameters. Then on each of those objects do a get_body() then you'll have the string of the message.

Here's a simple example in python.  Sorry don't know ruby.

```
sqsConn = connect_to_region("us-west-1", # this is the region you created the queue in
                        aws_access_key_id=AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
                        aws_secret_access_key=AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY)

QUEUE = sqsConn.get_queue("my-queue") # the name of your queue

msgs = QUEUE.get_messages(num_messages=10, # try and get 10 messages
                          wait_time_seconds=1, # wait 1 second for these messages
                          visibility_timeout=10) # keep them visible for 10 seconds

body = msgs[0].get_body() # get the string from the first object
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your help, even with Python it helped getting it!